# Windows Workflow 4.0 FlowSwitch not working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I'm creating a FlowChart within a Windows Workflow 4.0 project in Visual Studio 2010.  I've added a `FlowSwitch`with an expression of a variable passed in as an `In Argument` to the `Activity`.  I can debug and see the values are passed in correctly, however my FlowSwitch is not switching at all to a case that is defined as the value being passed in.  I've defined the FlowSwitch going to the Activity as the numeric value that the `In Argument` should be equal to.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: It sucks when beta software has bugs, hey?

Comment: Especially on something so elemental to it's feature set.  I'm trying to test out FlowCharts versus regular activities and it's just not working..

Comment: This isn't even working with hardcoded values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A FlowSwitch works with string values at the moment. Try converting the InArgument to a string.

Example XAML:

```
<p:Activity mc:Ignorable="" x:Class="WorkflowConsoleApplication2.Flowchart1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities/design" xmlns:__Flowchart1="clr-namespace:WorkflowConsoleApplication2;" xmlns:av="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:sad="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Debugger;assembly=System.Activities" xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <p:Flowchart StartNode="{x:Reference __ReferenceID0}" sad:XamlDebuggerXmlReader.FileName="c:\temp\WorkflowConsoleApplication2\WorkflowConsoleApplication2\Flowchart1.xaml">
    <WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, s:Object">
        <av:Point x:Key="ShapeLocation">275,10</av:Point>
        <av:Size x:Key="ShapeSize">50,50</av:Size>
        <av:PointCollection x:Key="ConnectorLocation">300,60 300,110</av:PointCollection>
      </scg:Dictionary>
    </WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
    <p:FlowSwitch x:Name="__ReferenceID0" Expression="[&quot;2&quot;]">
      <p:FlowSwitch.Default>
        <p:FlowStep x:Name="__ReferenceID1">
          <WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
            <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, s:Object">
              <av:Point x:Key="ShapeLocation">235,293</av:Point>
              <av:Size x:Key="ShapeSize">200,34</av:Size>
            </scg:Dictionary>
          </WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
          <p:WriteLine>["Default"]</p:WriteLine>
        </p:FlowStep>
      </p:FlowSwitch.Default>
      <WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
        <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, s:Object">
          <av:Point x:Key="ShapeLocation">270,110</av:Point>
          <av:Size x:Key="ShapeSize">60,60</av:Size>
          <av:PointCollection x:Key="Default">300,170 285,170 285,283 335,283 335,293</av:PointCollection>
          <av:PointCollection x:Key="1Connector">300,170 300,205 330,205</av:PointCollection>
          <av:PointCollection x:Key="2Connector">300,170 300,180 290,180 290,270 340,270</av:PointCollection>
        </scg:Dictionary>
      </WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      <p:FlowStep x:Name="__ReferenceID2">
        <x:Key>
          <x:String>1</x:String>
        </x:Key>
        <WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
          <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, s:Object">
            <av:Point x:Key="ShapeLocation">330,188</av:Point>
            <av:Size x:Key="ShapeSize">200,34</av:Size>
          </scg:Dictionary>
        </WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
        <p:WriteLine>["Its 1 "]</p:WriteLine>
      </p:FlowStep>
      <p:FlowStep x:Name="__ReferenceID3">
        <x:Key>
          <x:String>2</x:String>
        </x:Key>
        <WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
          <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, s:Object">
            <av:Point x:Key="ShapeLocation">340,253</av:Point>
            <av:Size x:Key="ShapeSize">200,34</av:Size>
          </scg:Dictionary>
        </WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
        <p:WriteLine>["Its 2"]</p:WriteLine>
      </p:FlowStep>
    </p:FlowSwitch>
    <x:Reference>__ReferenceID2</x:Reference>
    <x:Reference>__ReferenceID3</x:Reference>
    <x:Reference>__ReferenceID1</x:Reference>
  </p:Flowchart>
</p:Activity>
```

Comment: I've tried Argument.ToString and even hardcoded a String "15000" and still it doesn't work.  Any thoughts?

Comment: It works for me :-) In the FlowSwitch Expression I entered "2" (including quotes) or 2.ToString(). In the FlowStep I entered 2 (without quotes as this is a string not an expression. 
If have added the XAML I use to the original post.

Comment: Got beta 2 today.  No longer a problem but I appreciate your effort greatly.